# Saving data to .mat file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, save

I'm new to MATLAB, and I can't manage to make my function work in order to save my data into a `.mat` file.

**The input:**

- A structure, with 5 fields:

  - `data`: 3D matrix of 19x1000x143
  - `labels`: 1x143 matrix with `1` or `-1` in it
  - `subject_number`: an integer
  - `sampling_rate`: an integer, 500 Hz
  - `channel_names`: 1x19 matrix with text in it
- `name`: a string for the name of the file
- `clean`: a matrix 1x143 with `1` or `0` in it.

The idea is to save only the clean data, marked as `1` in the clean matrix.

```
 If clean(i) is equal to 1:
      save data(:,:,i) and labels(:,i)
```

This is the code I've tried to implement in the saving.m file:

```
function saving(EEG_struct, clean, name)

subject_number = EEG_struct.subject_number;
fs = EEG_struct.sampling_rate;
chan_names = EEG_struct.channel_names;
nb_epoch = size(EEG_struct.data, 3);

for j=1:nb_epoch
    if clean(j) == 1
        % Keep the epoch and label
        data = cat(3, data, EEG_struct.data(:,:,j));
        labels = cat(2, labels, EEG_struct.labels(:,j));
    end
end

save(name, data, labels, subject_number, fs, chan_names)
```

As you can see, I would like to save the data as a structure with the same shape as the `EEG_struct` input.
Moreover, I would like to use a parfor instead of a for, but it raised me an error I didn't quite get:

```
An UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the workers for 'data'.  This might be because the file containing 'data' is not accessible on the workers.  Use addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the required files to be attached.  See the documentation for 'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles' for more details. Caused by: Undefined function or variable 'data'.
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `clean` variable as a logical index and parse out your data and labels at once.  So there is no need for a loop.

Also the save command needs the "names" of the vars to save not the variables themselves.  So I just put ' ' around each one.

```
function saving(EEG_struct, clean, name)

subject_number = EEG_struct.subject_number;
fs = EEG_struct.sampling_rate;
chan_names = EEG_struct.channel_names;
nb_epoch = size(EEG_struct.data, 3);

%No need for a loop at all
data  = EEG_struct.data(:,:,logical(clean));
labels = EEG_struct.labels(logical(clean));  %This is a 1xN so I removed the extra colon operator
save(name, 'data', 'labels', 'subject_number', 'fs', 'chan_names');
```

**EDIT:**
Per you comment if you want to just leave everything in the structure.  I gave you 2 options for how to save it.

```
function saving(EEG_struct, clean, name)
%Crop out ~clead data
EEG_struct.data  = EEG_struct.data(:,:,logical(clean));
EEG_struct.labels = EEG_struct.labels(logical(clean));  %This is a 1xN so I removed the extra colon operator
% Option 1
save(name, 'EEG_struct'); 
% Option2
save(name, '-struct', 'EEG_struct');
```

**Option 1** will directly save the struct to the MAT file.  So if you were to load the data back like this:

```
test = load(name);

test = 
        EEG_struct: [1x1 struct]
```

You would get your structure placed inside another structure ... which might not be ideal or require an extra line to de-nest it.  On the other hand just loading the MAT file with no outputs  `load(name)`  would put `EEG_struct`  into your current workspace.  But if in a function then it sort of springs into existence without every being declared which makes code a bit harder to follow.

**Option 2**  uses the '-struct' option which breaks out each field automatically into separate vars in the MAT file.  So loading like this:

EEG_struct = load(name);

Will put all the fields back together again.  To me at least this looks cleaner when done within a function but is probably just my preference

So comment out which ever you prefer.  Also, not I did not include `clean` in the save.  You could either append it to the MAT or add it to your structure.

Comment: Well thanks again, and how could we save this as a structure ? Like the EEG_struct.

Comment: @Mathieu  See my edit for saving the structure with various options.

Answer (score 1):

To get a structure the same as `EEG_struct` but with only the data/labels corresponding with the `clean` variable, you can simply make a copy of the existing structure and remove the rows where `clean=0`

```
function saving(EEG_struct, clean, name)

newstruct = EEG_struct;
newstruct.data(:,:,logical(~clean)) = '';
newstruct.labels(logical(~clean)) = '';

save(name,'newstruct');
```

Comment: Thanks, and let's say that the EEG_struct.data is a matrix 19x1000x134, and that I have in my workspace a matrix, data_filtered, of the same size 19x1000x134. How do I replace the data in the structure with the data that was filtered ? (and of course, keeping the logical cleaning).

Comment: `EEG_struct.data = data_filtered;` if you are doing this in the command window. If you want to do this in the function you will need to add the replacement data as an another input

Comment: Ok thanks ! One last question, how do you specify the folder of saving ?

Comment: By default it will save into the current folder. I think you can override that by putting the complete path as the name

Comment: @Mathieu Just make name the full path & file name ex. C:\path\to\MATIFLE.mat